# How to make multiple windows in Eclipse RCP e4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

We want to  achieve an RCP application which may  have multiple windows (`MWindow`)
for distinct data. The Windows must  be independent (unlike the Eclipse IDE new
window menu  entry), but  it must be possible  to copy & paste, drag & drop  things from
one window  into another one.  Imagine an application like  Word where  you can
have multiple documents  open.  We  tried  various  approaches,  but  it  is  quiet
difficult to find out the right e4 way:

### 1. Creating a new E4Application for each window

Our first approach was  to create and run a complete  new E4Application for each
new window.  But this sounds not to  be the right e4  way. Also it is  buggy: Key
bindings does  not work correct and also  the `LifecycleManager` is  called for  each new
application and therefor for each new window, which should not be.

```
E4Application application = new E4Application();
BundleContext context = InternalPlatform.getDefault().getBundleContext();
ServiceReference<?> appContextService = context.getServiceReference(IApplicationContext.class);
IApplicationContext iac = (IApplicationContext) context.getService(appContextService);
IWorkbench workbench = application.createE4Workbench(iac, display);
 final E4Workbench implementation = (E4Workbench) workbench;
implementation.createAndRunUI(workbench.getApplication());
```

This seems not the right approach to do it.

### 2. The Eclipse IDE approach

In the Eclipse IDE you can go to  the menu and click `Window -> New Window` which
will open  a complete  new top level  window. But it  is synchronized:  Open the
same text file in both windows and editing  it in the first one will alter it in
the other one  too. Albeit we tried  that approach by simply  copy and pasting it
from `org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenInNewWindowAction#run()`:

```
// Does not work because we do not have the RCP3 workbench in RCP4.
final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
final IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
final IWorkbenchPage activePage = workbenchWindow.getActivePage();
final String perspectiveId;

if (activePage != null && activePage.getPerspective() != null) {
    perspectiveId = activePage.getPerspective().getId();
} else {
    perspectiveId = workbenchWindow.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry().getDefaultPerspective();
}

workbenchWindow.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(perspectiveId, null);
```

It looks like that the Eclipse IDE  uses the RCP3 compatibility layer. We didn't
found    a   way    to   obtain    the   `IWorkbench`    object.   Neither    by
`PlatformUI#getWorkbench()`,  nor via  the application  context, nor  the bundle
context.

### 3. Clone the main window

We stumbled upon [Opening multiple instances of an MTrimmedWindow complete with perspectives etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740891/opening-multiple-instances-of-a)
n-mtrimmedwindow-complete-with-perspectives-etc  and did  a  lot  of trial  and
error and came up with this muddy code:

```
class ElementCloningBasedCreator {

    EModelService models = ...; // injected
    MApplication app = ...; // injected

    public void openNewWindow() {
        MWindow originWindow = (MWindow) models.find("the.main.window.id", app);
        MWindow newWindow = (MWindow) models.cloneElement(originWindow, null);

        MPerspectiveStack newPerspectiveStack =
            (MPerspectiveStack) models.find(the.main.perspective.stack.id, newWindow);
        newPerspectiveStack.setParent((MElementContainer) newWindow);

        addTo(app, newWindow);

        // Clone the shared elements. If we don't do that the rendering somewhere 
        // deep in the rabbit hole throws assertion erros because the recurisve 
        // finding of an element fails because the search root is null.
        for (final MUIElement originSharedElement : originWindow.getSharedElements()) {
            final MUIElement clonedSharedElement = models.cloneElement(originSharedElement, null);
            clonedSharedElement.setParent((MElementContainer) newWindow);
            newWindow.getSharedElements().add(clonedSharedElement);
        }

        cloneSnippets(app, originWindow, newPerspectiveStack, newWindow);
        newWindow.setContext(createContextForNewWindow(originWindow, newWindow));
        newWindow.setToBeRendered(true);
        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        newWindow.setOnTop(true);
        models.bringToTop(newWindow);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void addTo(MElementContainer target, MUIElement child) {
        child.setParent(target);
        target.getChildren().add(child);
    }

    /**
     * Clone each snippet that is a perspective and add the cloned perspective 
     * into the main PerspectiveStack.
     */
    private void cloneSnippets(MApplication app, MWindow originWindow,
        MPerspectiveStack newPerspectiveStack, MWindow newWindow) {
        boolean isFirstSnippet = true;

        for (MUIElement snippet : app.getSnippets()) {
            if (ignoreSnippet(snippet)) {
                continue;
            }

            String snipetId = snippet.getElementId();
            MPerspective clonedPerspective = 
                (MPerspective) models.cloneSnippet(app, snipetId, originWindow);
            findPlaceholdersAndCloneReferencedParts(clonedPerspective, newWindow);
            addTo(newPerspectiveStack, clonedPerspective);

            if (isFirstSnippet) {
                newPerspectiveStack.setSelectedElement(clonedPerspective);
                isFirstSnippet = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean ignoreSnippet(MUIElement snippet) {
        return !(snippet instanceof MPerspective);
    }

    private void findPlaceholdersAndCloneReferencedParts(MPerspective clonedPerspective, MWindow newWindow) {
        List<MPlaceholder> placeholders = 
            models.findElements(clonedPerspective, null, MPlaceholder.class, null);

        for (MPlaceholder placeholder : placeholders) {
            MUIElement reference = placeholder.getRef();

            if (reference != null) {
                placeholder.setRef(models.cloneElement(placeholder.getRef(), null));
                placeholder.getRef().setParent((MElementContainer) newWindow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code does  not really work and  we really need some hints/advices  how to do
it right, because of the lack of official documentation. The questions open are:

1. Do  we need  to clone the  shared objects and  if not  how do we  prevent the
   errors during  rendering)?
2. We only  saw code where  the cloned  elements are
   added  to the  parent  via  `getChildren().add()`, but  we  found  out that  the
   children din't get the  parent automatically and it is `null`  though. Is it the
   right pattern to  add the parent to the  child too?
3. We have  the deep feeling
   that we are doing  it not right. It looks way too complicated  what we do here. Is
   there a simpler/better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20740891/2670892

Comment: I've found that question. My hope is to get a more detailed answer when I provide some example source.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `EModelService` `cloneSnippet` method to do this.

Design your `MTrimmedWindow` (or whatever type of window you want) in the `Snippets` section of the Application.e4xmi. Be sure that the `To Be Rendered` and `Visible` flags are checked. You may need to set the width and height bounds (and you may want to set the x and y position as well).

Your command handler to create the new window would simply be:

```
@Execute
public void execute(EModelService modelService, MApplication app)
{
  MTrimmedWindow newWin = (MTrimmedWindow)modelService.cloneSnippet(app, "id of the snippet", null);

  app.getChildren().add(newWin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good hint. Is it not necessary to set the app as parent to the newWin?

Comment: With this approach we have the problem that SWT complains that in the Application.e4xmi no top level window is defined.

Comment: You need to have one main window in the normal place in the e4xmi. The Snippet is for the second and subsequent windows. It might be possible to create the first window from the snippet during the app startup but I have not seen that done.

Comment: We only have one type of window, is it somehow possible to defien it as a snippet and use this snippet in the Application.e4xmi for the main window?

Comment: As I said it might be possible in the LifeCycle class but I haven't seen any code that does it. You can also use Shared Elements with Placeholders to share things between different windows.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so far. If we have a solution I show it here.