# Open new views on a detached windows by default

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm developing a RCP application and I want to give the user the ability to configure if new views will be openned on a new detached window or will open attached on the main window.

Is there a way to do that on Eclipse 4?

To open a view i'm using this method:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView( id );
```

Comment: Note: PlatformUI is not e4 it is Eclipse 3 compatability mode.

Comment: For e4 see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36605105/2670892)